# For loop is not running for float values

Tags: php, for-loop, floating-point

i have a for loop like below

```
<?php 

 for($i=0;$i<=10;$i+0.4){

 echo $i."<br>";
 }

 ?>
```

this code prints the value of i till 9.6 not 10.

why it returns the value of i=10 at last.

Comment: You made a mistake, `$i+0.4` was probably `$i+=0.4`, since you said it goes up till 9.6, rendering 3 answers below invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Use `+=` to increment it, instead of just plus. As it is now, its an infinite loop for me.

Edit: For some reason PHP doesn't work properly with different types in loops.

This below should work

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i+=4){
   echo $i/10."<br>";
 }
```

Here's the `var_dump`

```
int(0)

float(0.4)

float(0.8)

float(1.2)

float(1.6)

int(2)

float(2.4)

float(2.8)

float(3.2)

float(3.6)

int(4)

float(4.4)

float(4.8)

float(5.2)

float(5.6)

int(6)

float(6.4)

float(6.8)

float(7.2)

float(7.6)

int(8)

float(8.4)

float(8.8)

float(9.2)

float(9.6)

int(10)
```

That's probably the auto-casting PHP is doing that is causing this

Comment: why it is not printing 10. i am only asking this.please

Answer (score 3):

because of representing of float numbers for machines - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

I'd recommend to use integer indexes for loops

Comment: +1. But using integer indexes is not always possible. In those cases you have to use the epsilon value - e.g. the allowed mistake. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with accurate FLOAT comparison (which takes place in <**=**).

Do it like this:

```
 for($i=0; $i<=100; $i+=4){
     echo ($i/10)."<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For exact comparison you can round those value , As like following ...

```
<?php

   for($i=0; round($i,1) <= 10; $i += 0.4){
      echo $i."<br/>";
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<?php 

 for($i=0;$i<=100;$i += 4){

 echo ($i/10)."<br>";
 }

 ?>
```

result here: http://codepad.org/CxvzEUeq

Comment: but actually i have two values one is $start and second is $end. these values can be any thing like float or int. so my for loop will be like for($i=$start;$<=$end;$i=+.4)

Comment: This gives problem when you do the comparison as suggested in another answer

Comment: @user1031816: I have posted another answer, which displays how the thing should be proppery done. With epsilon value.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php`

`for($i=0;$i<10;$i+0.4){`

`echo $i."<br>";`

`}`

`?>`

if u put i<=10 then it will continue printing to value 10 but if remove = sign then it will stop at 9!

Answer (score 0):

When comparing, you have to use the epsilon value, which denotes the allowed mistake when comparing float values.

```
$epsilon=0.000001; //a very small number

for($i=0; $i<10 or abs($i-10)<$epsilon; $i+=0.4){
   echo $i."<br>";
}
```