# How to explain the strange results for while loop with floating point in swift

Tags: while-loop, floating-point, swift3

I have tested while loop below and don’t understand the result.

```
var x: Float = 0.0
var counter = 0

 while x < 1.41
 {
     x += 0.1
     counter += 1

 }

 print (counter) // 15
 print (x) // 1.5
```

How is it possible to have the result x = 1.5 for the used while condition where x < 14.1 ? How to explain this result?

**Update:**
and one more. Why the results are  different for Double and Float ?

```
var x: Double = -0.5
var counter = 0

while x < 1.0
{
    x += 0.1
    counter += 1   
}

print (counter) // 16
print (x)//1.1

var x: Float = -0.5
var counter = 0

while x < 1.0
{
    x += 0.1
    counter += 1   
}

print (counter) // 15
print (x)//1.0
```

**Update 2**
and another one. Why there is no difference for < and <= conditions. Does it mean that usage of <= has no sense for floating point ?

```
var x: Double = 0.0
var counter = 0

while x < 1.5
{
    x += 0.1
    counter += 1
}

print (counter) // 15
print (x) //1.5


var x: Double = 0.0
var counter = 0

while x <= 1.5
{
    x += 0.1
   counter += 1
}

print (counter) // 15
print (x) //1.5
```

Comment: What value do you expect `x` to have at the start of the last iteration of the `while` loop? And what value will it have at the end of that final iteration?

Comment: @Hamish Ok, clear. I have added an update

Comment: Please don't combine several different questions in one; make a new question post instead!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop with float as counter, increasing by 0.01, does not print expected float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124040/for-loop-with-float-as-counter-increasing-by-0-01-does-not-print-expected-floa)

Comment: [For loop is not running for float values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8036368/995714), [Floating point inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4575643/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What else would you expect? The loop is executed 15 times. On the 14th time, x is 1.4 and so you add another 0.1, making it 1.5.

If you expect the loop to terminate at 1.4, you should increment x before checking the while condition, not after that.

If you expect the loop to terminate on 1.41, your increment is wrong and you should do

```
x += 0.01
```

instead, making it 141 iterations.

As for the second question, I am aware that `Float` should not be used for monetary calculations and such due to its lack of precision. However, I trusted `Double` so far, and the while loop in run 15 actually claims the Double value to be less than 1.0 while it is reported to be 1.0. We have got a precision problem here, as we can see if we substract x from 1.0:

```
print(1.0-x)
```

which returns: 1.11022302462516e-16

At the same time, `Float` seems to be unprecise in the other direction. In the last run, it is a little bigger than 0.9 (0.9 + 5.96046e-08), making it bigger than 10 in the following run.

The reason why `Double` and `Float` are wrong in different directions is just a matter of how the values are stored, and the result will be different depending on the number. For example, with 2.0 both actual values are bigger: `Double` by 4.440892..e-16 and `Float` by 2.38419e-07. For 3.0 `Double` is bigger by 1.33226e-15 and `Float` smaller by 7.1525e-07.

The same problems occur using x.isLess(than: 1.0), but this method is the basis for the < operator as of https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint/1849403-isless

`isLessThanOrEqualTo(1.0)`, on the other hand, seems to work reliably as expected.

This answer is pretty much a question itself by now, so I'm curious if anyone has an in-depth explanation of this...

**Update**

The more I think about it, the less of a Swift problem it is. Basically, you have that problem in all floating point calculations, because they are never precise. Both `Float` and `Double` are not precise, `Double` is just twice as accurate. However, this means that comparisons like `==` are useless with floating point values unless they are both rounded. Therefore, good advice in loops like those of yours with a known precision (in your case one decimal) would be to round to that precision before doing any kind of comparison. For example, this would fix the loop:

```
var x: Double = -0.5
var counter = 0

while (round(x * 1000) / 1000) < 1.0
{
    x += 0.1
    counter += 1   
}

print (counter) // 15
print (x)//1.0

var x: Float = -0.5
var counter = 0

while (round(x * 1000) / 1000) < 1.0
{
    x += 0.1
    counter += 1   
}

print (counter) // 15
print (x)//1.0
```

Comment: This is where the [**unit of least precision**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) comes in. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/float/1846050-ulp

Comment: @Lupinity Yes, agree, to round the values is a good solution !